# ADOMD.net Impersonate Windows User ID

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, impersonation, adomd.net

I am trying to connect to a SSAS Cube which uses windows authentication

My web application is stored on a seperate server the SQL Analysis Instance (lets says `ServerWebApp`)  and the SSAS Cube is on `ServerCUBE`

```
OLAPCon = New AdomdConnection("Provider=MSOLAP.4; roles=Administrator; Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True; EffectiveUserName=<Domain\Username>; " _
& " Initial Catalog=<DBName>; Data Source=<ServerCUBE>; ")
```

As SSAS uses Windows authentication I have tried to impersonate my windows login by specifing `EffectiveUserName` however, this doesn't seem to work as I am getting the follow error:

```
Either the user, Domain\ServerWebApp, does not have access to the <DBName> database, or the database does not exist.
```

As you can see it is using the web apps login ID not my windows ID

How would I impersonate my windows ID in the SSAS ADOMD connection string?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7250145/257299

Answer (score 0):

This is what tripped me up when I used EffectiveUserName. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn140245.aspx):

> To use [the EffectiveUserName] property, the caller must have
>   administrative permissions in Analysis Services.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the IIS server first by creating an Application pool first. Then you need to point this pool to the local path ( folder in C drive) which consists of msmdpump.dll and msmdpump files. Edit msmdpump file using notepad (remove localhost name and replace it with your SQL analysis server name). Provide the username of server name in place of domain\username.